# Pass a string from reader.onload to parent

Tags: reactjs, function, object, onload, reader

This is my code. I am trying to pass the treeContent out of the read.onload function. I can't get it to work.

console shows : outer undefined index.html:18 
                inner hello world;  index.html:15

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>File reader</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        function read(e) {
            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                const treeContent = reader.result;
                window.file = treeContent; 
                console.log('inner ' + window.file);              
            };
            reader.readAsText(e.target.files[0]);
            console.log('outer '+ window.file);
        }
    </script>
    <input type="file" onchange="read(event)" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does using an arrow function help? `reader.onload = () => { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

from what you posted it seems you never read any file. somewhere in your code you should call reader.readText(fileToRead)..

have a look at this bare minimum working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>File reader</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        function read(e) {
            let reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                const treeContent = reader.result;
                console.log(treeContent);
            };
            reader.readAsText(e.target.files[0]);
        }
    </script>
    <input type="file" onchange="read(event)" />
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

If you need to access treeContent in another function you should call the function inside the onload function:

```js
   function read(e) {
      let reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function (e) {
         const treeContent = reader.result;
         treeContentProcessor(treeContent);
      };
      reader.readAsText(e.target.files[0]);
   }

   function treeContentProcessor (content) {
      //here is where treeContent is required
      console.log(content);
   }
```

Comment: Brein, thanks a lot. I used the minimum working example as template to to pass the treeContent out of the read.onload function. It is still not working for me. Please help.

Comment: Hi @shihaifeng  By reading your log it looks like it's working! *outer* is still undefined because `reader.readAsText(e.target.files[0])` is an asynchronous method, so you can see the result only inside the onload function

Comment: Brein, thank you very much. How do I access the value of treecontent inside the onload? I need pass it to this.setstate to be used in another function. Cuilan

Comment: I have edited my answer to show you how I would do it

Comment: You are welcome, if you can mark this issue as solved it would be very much appreciated :)